# Phone number regex returning match and mismatch on same string?

Tags: php, regex

Ok so I've been using the following regex to match both national and international phone numbers:

```
$regex = "^(?!(?:\d*-){5,})(?!(?:\d* ){5,})\+?[\d- ]+$";
```

Of course I've tested this regex out on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/bR8nY1/1). It works as I expect it to.

Now here's the part where I implement this into my code:

```
<?php

//Check for valid Telephone Number (takes international numbers into account)
function phoneRegex($var){
    if(!preg_match("/^(?!(?:\d*-){5,})(?!(?:\d* ){5,})\+?[\d- ]+$/", $var)){
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

if(phoneRegex($_POST['phone'])){
    $error .= "The phone number is incorrect.";
}

?>
```

**The Issue**
Now whenever I type: 0123456789 with my normal number keys, the function returns false. If I type the same with the numpad keys, it returns true. I've tried echoing `$_POST['phone']` back to see if there's any difference, but there isn't. Both return the string 0123456789. I should add that I've echo'd these back through a Javascript alert to make sure the string was returned as plain text. Is there anyone able to tell me what's going on?

**Edit**
Someone mentioned keycodes from a different question to mark this as a duplicate. Keycodes are there to detect which key exactly is pressed. This however has no effect on the ASCII values of these keys. A 5 from the top keys on a keyboard for example has a different keycode than the 5 on the numpad. However, both have the same ASCII values. Therefor the solution / answer to this problem has nothing to do with keycodes.

**ASCII debug info**
When I debugged "0123456789" with top number keys, it returned:

> key 1 has ascii value: 48
>  key 2 has ascii value: 49
>  key 3
>   has ascii value: 50
>  key 4 has ascii value: 51
>  key 5 has
>   ascii value: 52
>  key 6 has ascii value: 53
>  key 7 has ascii
>   value: 54
>  key 8 has ascii value: 55
>  key 9 has ascii value:
>   56
>  key 10 has ascii value: 57

After debugging "0123456789" with numpad keys, it returned:

> key 1 has ascii value: 48
>  key 2 has ascii value: 49
>  key 3
>   has ascii value: 50
>  key 4 has ascii value: 51
>  key 5 has
>   ascii value: 52
>  key 6 has ascii value: 53
>  key 7 has ascii
>   value: 54
>  key 8 has ascii value: 55
>  key 9 has ascii value:
>   56
>  key 10 has ascii value: 57
>  key 11 has ascii value:
>   60
>  key 12 has ascii value: 98
>  key 13 has ascii value:
>   114
>  key 14 has ascii value: 62

So it seems 4 more keys are added to the string when using numpad.

Comment: Double the backslashes. Or use single apostrophes: `if(!preg_match('/^(?!(?:\d*-){5,})(?!(?:\d* ){5,})\+?[\d- ]+$/', $var)){`

Comment: @stribizhev Tried both as you suggested. It had no effect.

Comment: @stribizhev I'm not sure. I've found this one here on SO as an accepted answer. I've tested it out with a couple of strings on regex101 and it worked perfectly. Now I've stumbled on this strange issue.

Comment: My overall answer is to skip this regex stuff.  But as far as not working w/ normal number keys vs. numpad.. it sounds like this isn't really a regex issue but some kind of issue with your keyboard sending keys in a different char code somehow? maybe try `explode()` and `ord` each digit to compare.

Comment: @CrayonViolent I see. Thanks for that suggestion. Will surely help me debug this. If only for learning purposes. Looking at where I'm going use this script (it's for a CRM on an intranet system), I think trying to secure this with regex might be overkill for something this simple. The idea was to make sure a correct phone number is added as of course we need to be able to contact customers.

Comment: @icecub to be clear, i mentioned `explode` and `ord` as a means to try and debug the problem, not as an alt method to regex.  My thought is that the regex is failing because the "numbers" entered in from your "regular" keys aren't really the same as the ones from your keypad for unknown reasons

Comment: @CrayonViolent Ye I understood that. What bugs me the most though is that regex101 accepts both input keys. It's just my script bugging out. Still you've given me a way to at least see what's going on. Thanks again.

Comment: @Tro Keycodes are something completely different than character ascii values. Which in this case is what we're talking about.

Comment: @CrayonViolent I've edited my question with the debugging results you've suggested. But instead of clearing it up, it only made me more confused. Do you have any idea what's going on?

Comment: @CrayonViolent Never mind. It's a firefox bug adding `<br>` to contenteditable fields.

Comment: aha! yeah I saw the additional ascii codes and looked them up and saw it "spelled" `<br>` which explains why you weren't seeing it when you echo'd out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay real-talk:

Some people use parens. Some people use spaces in various places. Some people use dots and/or dashes. Some may or may not actually put a +.

On top of that, the only way to ensure the number is *real* is to pick up the phone and dial it.

The best thing you can do for both your visitors' and your own sanity, is to not try to force or match for formats. At the end of the day, the only thing that matters are the numbers.

If you really want to have the numbers separated to know the components, make separate input fields for them. But are you even going to have it split up as separate fields in a database? I rarely see people actually do this.

Do yourself and your visitors a favor: strip out anything that is not a number, check if it resembles a proper length with a simple `strlen`, and call it a day

Comment: Although I appreciate your input, this isn't exactly an answer to my question or the issue I'm facing? Even though you're probebly right, it's still very strange a regex accepts input from the numpad but not the normal numbers in a keyboard.

Comment: @icecub yeah I realize this isn't a direct answer to your issue. I made a comment on the question for that.  I was just kind of posting this as a "sidenote"

Comment: Ok so after having to deal with this issue long enough, I've decided to accept your answer as answered and be done with this. It's not worth losing so much time of something so minor. Thanks a lot for all your help!